# Filter in Android grid in Genexus

Tags: genexus, genexus-sd

I have a grid in a Smart Devices panel.

[image]

The data fetches correctly, but if I add a filter it appears on the screen, it stays fixed at the top of the page and it is as if the grid is scrolling over it ("Ricerca per 'ga' " in the example, "search for 'ga')

[image]

[image]

This is what appears in the genexus live inspector, the label is in the "grid" layer, but I can't manipulate or manage it in any way.
I'm working with genexus 17u10.

What is going on? Why does the filter behave like this?
The same happens in grids created by genexus with workwithdevices.

Can I fix it somehow, maybe with some specific class?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This problem [was fixed in Genexus v18u1](https://www.genexus.com/en/developers/websac?data=52097;;).
You should update your version.

Comment: Another solution I've found is to add a margin top to the grid